# select value i inserted in same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `receipt` where I insert values into table i want select column (ID) value

query

```
   ("INSERT INTO `receipt` (`ID`, `Totalamount`, `Printdate`, `paidby`) 
        VALUES (NULL, '$treasury[value_sum]', NOW() , '$treasury[addby]')")
```

Comment: I can guess that ID is auto_increment , no Null and it's your primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column `ID` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, use `LAST_INSERT_ID();` to get the last generated ID.

```
INSERT INTO `receipt` (`ID`, `Totalamount`, `Printdate`, `paidby`) 
VALUES (NULL, '$treasury[value_sum]', NOW() , '$treasury[addby]')

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS LAST_GENERATED_ID
```

Once you executed the query, get this column `LAST_GENERATED_ID` in your application layer.